# Â£ still appearing in email even after putting html and php to UTF-8

Tags: php, html, utf-8

i have set the php and html to UTF-8 and in my email the A£ still appears, i dont know what im doing wrong. Please ask for any code, instead of covering your screen with pointless code i thought it better if you ask what code you need

Comment: What mail headers are you sending?

Comment: do you mean this $headers = "Quote Request From: $email";

Comment: @EmilVikström i dont know what you mean, could you speak to me like i am very stupid please :)

Comment: Please post the e-mail function

Comment: I suggest you open up a regular e-mail message in its original form ("View original" or similar). You will see a couple of mail headers followed by the mail body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to send a header indicating to the mail reader what character set you are using. The header for this is the same as in HTTP:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

If you are using the regular [mail](http://php.net/mail) function, put it with the fourth parameter (`$additional_headers`):

```
$headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```